How to get access to `TextToSpeechService` instance on Android?
I need to generate spoken text as raw audio stream (e.g. an array of PCM floats). TextToSpeechService appears to have exactly the interface I need. How can I get it for the default system voice/engine?
All the examples I can find use higher-level TextToSpeech class, which can not render to raw audio streams. The best it provides is temporary files.
